# virtuemart javascriptto get thumbnail as larger pic

Tags: javascript, virtuemart

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_images; $i++) 
    {
    $image = $this->product->images[$i];
?>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="change(<?php echo $image->file_url; ?>)"><?php echo $image->displayMediaThumb('class="product-image"style="cursor: pointer"',false,""); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(url)
    {
        alert(url);
    }       
</script>
```

[image]

i want to change image shown in big pic when user clicks on thumbnail

Comment: check this link http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-virtuemart-product-image-zoom

Answer (score 0):

```
       in components/com_virtuemart/views/product_details/default_images.php       

             if (!empty($this->product->images)) 
             {
          $image = $this->product->images[0];
         ?>
          <div class="main-image">

      <?php
    echo $image->displayMediaFull('id="product_image"',true,"rel='vm-additional- images'");
?>

     <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>







              <script type="text/javascript"> 
              function change(url)
               {
                   document.getElementById('product_image').src=url;
               }        
              </script>
```